# How can I generate Visual Studio projects for a specific configuration?

Tags: msbuild, cmake, sfml

Using CMake's `ExternalProject_Add`, I automate builds of my dependencies. However, I build configurations don't match in the end even though I pass `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` as described [in the Tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php).

```
# SFML
include(ExternalProject)
set(SFML_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML)

# Download, configure, build and install.
ExternalProject_Add(SFML
    # DEPENDS
    PREFIX         ${SFML_PREFIX}
    TMP_DIR        ${SFML_PREFIX}/temp
    STAMP_DIR      ${SFML_PREFIX}/stamp
    #--Download step--------------
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG        e2c378e9d1
    #--Update/Patch step----------
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    #--Configure step-------------
    SOURCE_DIR     ${SFML_PREFIX}/source
    CMAKE_ARGS     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${SFML_PREFIX}/install
                   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
                   -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}
    #--Build step-----------------
    BINARY_DIR     ${SFML_PREFIX}/build
    #--Install step---------------
    INSTALL_DIR    ${SFML_PREFIX}/install
)

# Set root so that find module knows where to look.
set(SFML_ROOT ${SFML_PREFIX}/install)
```

How can I generate a Visual Studio project that builds release versions, instead of falling back to debug mode with no command line arguments provided? Is there even a way to generate a project that builds both release and debug versions with one `msbuild Project.sln`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multi-configuration generators (e.g., Visual Studio), the actual build configuration (Debug or Release) is specified upon building the project. Setting the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` at configuration time does not have an effect.

When a Visual Studio generator is used, the `ExternalProject_Add` command sets up the build process of the external project so that the project uses the build configuration currently selected in the IDE. In CMake terms that means the following code is executed:

```
cmake --build <BINARY_DIR> --config ${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}
```

For Visual Studio 10 `${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` is replaced with `$(Configuration)` at build time.

To always do a Release build, you have to replace the `ExternalProject_Add` default build step with a custom one:

```
ExternalProject_Add(SFML
    ...
    #--Build step-----------------
    BINARY_DIR ${SFML_PREFIX}/build
    BUILD_COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <BINARY_DIR> --config Release
    ...
    )
```

To build both the Release and Debug versions, add another cmake invocation:

```
ExternalProject_Add(SFML
    ...
    #--Build step-----------------
    BINARY_DIR ${SFML_PREFIX}/build
    BUILD_COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <BINARY_DIR> --config Release
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <BINARY_DIR> --config Debug
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So I can just use `cmake --build --config Release` to build a configured project in release mode? It there an option to build both Release and Debug in one command? Moreover, in single configuration environments (I suppose GCC is one), can I still override the configuration type on building with the `--config` flag?

Comment: 1st question: Yes.
2nd question: Not with a single command. You have to invoke cmake twice.
3rd question: No.

Comment: But `cmake --build` defaults to the configuration set in `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, right?

Comment: No. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is ignored for multi-configuration builds. The default build configuration is usually the first one in `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`.