# Passing variables down to subdirectory only

Tags: cmake

How do I pass project specific variables down to subdirectory? I wonder if there is a "official" way of doing this:

```
# (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is one of None, Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo)

# ...

# set specific build type for 'my_library'
set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_COPY "${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" )
set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )
add_subdirectory( "my_library" )
set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_COPY} )

# continue with original build type
# ...
```

The library/subdirectory `my_library` should always be buildt with type `"Release"`, main project and other subdirectories should be buildt with type defined by configuration. I am not able to modify the `CMakeLists.txt`of `my_library`.

Comment: About `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/2288008

Comment: Your question is to pass different flags to different directories ?

Comment: For most details see @ruslo comment/link. Just wanted to add that - if we are talking about VS - what you see in the "Configuration Manager" when opening the generated VS solution is hard-coded into the VS generator. See [cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L628). The project's config will always match the solution's config. I recommend to generate `my_library` as an [external project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440988/how-can-i-generate-visual-studio-projects-for-a-specific-configuration).

Comment: @coincoin: No, my project uses external libraries, which are git submodules. These have their own `CMakeLists.txt`, so I am not able to modify these. I want one of these libraries to be built as `Release`, since this is a pretty heavy OpenGL library. But I want debug symbols in my own code, i.e. `Debug`.

Comment: @ruslo: Thanks for the link. This means that I should not pass `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` down to other cmake directories.

My question is still open; how can I pass different values down without changing the value of current `CMakeLists.txt`, in a nice way.

Comment: @telephone From my experience there is no such option, however you can always write your own wrapper

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering the revised question in your comment (how can I pass *different* values), so values other then CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`:

There's no extra machinery for this. If the variable is project specific, you just set the variable:

```
    set(MYLIB_SOME_OPTION OFF)
    add_subdirectory(mylib)
```

If it's more general, you need to revert it:

```
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_SAVED "${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}")
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
    add_subdirectory(mylib)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_SAVED}")
```

Or you can put it into a function and you don't need to revert the variables you changed since functions has a scope.

Comment: Well, it will be visible in the function which can in turn forward it to the calling scope. But you're right, if the subdirectory sets a variable for PARENT_SCOPE it's simpler no to use a function but the 'more general' example above

Comment: @tamas.kenez: Given that "There's no extra machinery for this" is true, your answer is accepted.

Comment: Hi how Is it possible to use options defined in main CMakeLists.txt and use the variable name in the subdirectories CMakeList.txt?

Comment: so you can call "add_subdirectory" out from a function and set variables there?