# cmake, missing feature set_directory_property?

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project and I want to do the following :

```
set_directory_property(DIRECTORY glfw BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
add_subdirectory(glfw)
```

I want to force the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to be ON, but only in the scope of the 'glfw' sub directory. Without touching the glfw cmake files.

Is it possible ?

There is no set_directory_property, only a get_directory_property :-(

Thanks

Comment: There is command [set_directory_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set_directory_properties.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variables down to subdirectory only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985215/passing-variables-down-to-subdirectory-only)

Answer (score 2):

The [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) is a variable not a directory property. And the [`VARIABLES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html) directory property is read-only.

So in your case you just do:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
add_subdirectory(glfw)
unset(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. It seems cmake still interpret BUILD_SHARED_LIBS at OFF !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I had to use the following :

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE "" INTERNAL FORCE)
add_subdirectory(glfw)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE "" INTERNAL FORCE)
```

Thanks for your help !